# how to enable firebase notifications in ionic android application

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

i want to build an application and use firebase for notification done a lot of search over google but did not find any good guide and solution , everything i tried ended into some errors . i tried ionic docs but they are all messy after the ionic v4 they shows everything about v4 i have my app almost finished up just this thing remains .
i will appreciate any help . 
Any idea how to proceed? I'm most probably not configuring Firebase properly. I have placed `google-services.json` in the root directory, no problems there. but after that its all out of my understanding

```
 AN ERROR OCCURRED WHILE RUNNING ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID-150482406038 --SAVE EXIT CODE 1
```

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/

Comment: Since the 2.0.0 version of the plugin, you do not need to specify the SENDERID anymore, since the plugin is using the`google-services.json` file. So just run `cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push` to add the plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Got this Working . Thanks everyone for help!**
**refrences used-**

- *https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/push/*
- *https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push*

works for

1. ionic 3.20.1
2. cordova 8.1.2

steps i followed

1. Removed my android platform using `ionic cordova platform
   removeandroid`  then i created it agin `ionic cordova platform add
   android`.  just to avoid any errors which my be there with my old
   android version.
2. Got the `google-services.json` and placed it in the
       `rootDirectoryOfApp\platforms\android\app`
3. then i run `$ ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push $ npm
   install --save @ionic-native/push@4`
4. Edit `config.xml` look for `<platform name="android">` under that i
   wrote `<resource-file src="google-services.json"
   target="app/google-services.json" />`
5. Edit `package.json` look for `"phonegap-plugin-push"` and edit it
   something like this

   ```
   "phonegap-plugin-push": {
       "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V13_VERSION": "27.+", // already there
       "FCM_VERSION": "11.6.2", // already there
       "SENDER_ID": "numeric key obtain from firebase console" // added
     },
   ```
6. Open `app.module.ts` and import `import { Push } from
   '@ionic-native/push';` add    Push under providers there `... 
   providers: [
       StatusBar,
       SplashScreen,
       Push, ....`
7. Then in a provider 
   i imported `import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push';`
   then in costructor i  added `private push: Push,`
   and in the class of that provider i wrote a function like below

   pushSetup(){

   ```
   // to check if we have permission
   this.push.hasPermission()

   .then((res: any) => {
   if (res.isEnabled) {
   console.log('We have permission to send push notifications');
   } else {

   console.log('We do not have permission to send push notifications');
   }
   });    
   // Create a channel (Android O and above). You'll need to provide the id, description and importance properties.

   this.push.createChannel({
   id: "testchannel1",
   description: "My first test channel",
   // The importance property goes from 1 = Lowest, 2 = Low, 3 = Normal, 4 = High and 5 = Highest.
   importance: 3

   }).then(() => console.log('Channel created'));
   // Delete a channel (Android O and above)
   this.push.deleteChannel('testchannel1').then(() => console.log('Channel deleted'));  



   // Return a list of currently configured channels
   this.push.listChannels().then((channels) => console.log('List of channels', channels))    
   // to initialize push notifications  

   const options: PushOptions = {
   android: {
   senderID:"150482406038",
   },

   ios: {
   alert: 'true',
    badge: true,
   sound: 'false'
   },     
   };

   const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);     
   pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));     
   pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', registration));     
   pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
   }
   ```
8. Now imported that provider where I want to use that , and called
   that function from there . but call it only after
   `this.platform.ready().then(() => {` or when a successful login.

**I have shared this because i found it little difficult and got confusing guides over web** 
*Please comment if you found it wrong or not working in your case.*

Comment: Step 2 is not necessary, `google-services.json` can be placed at the same level as config.xml, you don't need to put it in platforms/android/app, since at step 4 you're specifying the resource-file directive

Comment: @saperlipopette thanks for informing i didn't know that I just did what I can understand

Comment: @ramashish tomar can u share the serve side codes as well?

Comment: @Abdu4 I am sorry i work on client side only server Side is handled by someone else

Comment: @ramashishtomar I am facing issues related to sound here it is can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319165/default-sound-not-playing-in-android-v9-but-working-on-andoird-v7-ionic-v3-cor

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this tutorial: https://medium.com/@felipepucinelli/how-to-add-push-notifications-in-your-cordova-application-using-firebase-69fac067e821 and Android push notifications worked out of the box. Good luck!

^ you might wanna try the cordova-plugin-firebase plugin as Chrillewoodz has mentioned

Comment: This tutorial has been written in 2017, all the screenshots of Firebase console are obsolete. Moreover, 80% of the tutorial is dedicated to iOS, while question is only about Android

Comment: Yeah, although it still works in Ionic v3, Android included (I haven't tested in the v4), and the cordova-plugin-firebase is the plugin mentioned in the Ionic's official documentations. What's wrong with the working solution, even if its old? :)